# Having trouble referencing a dictionary

Tags: c#, discord.net

So I am having some trouble referencing a dictionary. I am trying to make an economy discord bot. I want the user to setup the dictionary with the command !g setup, then type !g register to register their Discord ID to the dictionary.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Discord.Commands;
using Discord;

namespace Games_Bot.Modules
{
    public class Commands : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
    {
        public Dictionary<ulong, int> economy;

        [Command("g setup")]
        public async Task Setup()
        {
            economy = new Dictionary<ulong, int>();
        }

        [Command("g register")]
        public async Task Register()
        {
            var userInfo = Context.User;
            try
            {
                if (economy.ContainsKey(userInfo.Id) == false) { economy.Add(userInfo.Id, 0); }
            }
            catch { return; }
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to reference the dictionary in Register(), Visual Studio throws me a
[null error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aG2m8.png). Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I know what a null reference is. I just don't understand how this case is a null reference. I tell the dictionary type and give it a name, then I assign it a value.

Comment: @PixelatedLagg Presumably a new instance of `Commands` is created each time. I expect you issue the setup command, an instance of `Commands` gets created, the `Setup()` method runs. Next, you issue the register command, a new instance of `Commands` gets created, and the `Register()` method runs.

Comment: The reason I don't declare dictionary outside the void is because every time you call on a command, the whole script is called on again and it would just re-declare the dictionary each time.

Comment: Re-read my comment carefully.

Comment: I only know that the whole script gets called on again - I don't know if an instance gets created each time, I'm not that familiar with Discord.Net. If you are correct and the whole script gets initialized again, how would I go about declaring and adding values to a dictionary?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Discord.Net at all, but the behaviour you've described is congruent with that. Are you using dependency injection?

Comment: There is no need to use `ContainsKey` and `Add`. Just call `TryAdd`. Or, even better, use a `ConcurrentDictionary`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you called `Setup`, something you didn't claim. If so, then I presume a new instance of `Commands` is create for each request. As such, you could use

```
public class Commands : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
{
    public static Dictionary<ulong, int> economy = new Dictionary<ulong, int>();

    [Command("g register")]
    public async Task Register()
    {
        var userInfo = Context.User;
        try
        {
            if (economy.ContainsKey(userInfo.Id) == false) { economy.Add(userInfo.Id, 0); }
        }
        catch { return; }
    }
}
```

Note the `static` modifier.

(I'm not familiar with the library in question. I use DSharpPlus for my bot.)

Comment: Thank you so much! My mind went completely numb for the past few hours, and I forgot about the static modifier!